# compiling the linux kernel [ make menuconfig error ]

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gnu-make

When trying to compile the Linux kernel 5.16.10 make menuconfig complains:

```
aruna@debian:/media/aruna/linux-next/home/linux-5.16.10$ make menuconfig
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/mconf
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/confdata.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/expr.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/menu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/symbol.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/util.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/util.o: warning: relocation against `free@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:104: scripts/kconfig/mconf] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:619: menuconfig] Error 2
```

After checking gcc builtin flags I see:

```
aruna@debian:/media/aruna/linux-next/home/linux-5.16.10$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-10-Km9U7s/gcc-10-10.2.1/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-10-Km9U7s/gcc-10-10.2.1/debian/tmp-gcn/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
```

So gcc uses **--enable-default-pie** which prevents me from using make menuconfig. What would be the best way to fix/resolve this please ? Can I override gcc flags ? If so how ?

Comment: You could try with `make KBUILD_CFLAGS=-no-pie menuconfig`

Comment: HI Marco thank you I tried but same error: http://codepad.org/yd473eiH

Comment: Not sure if this is enough, but try with `ccflags-y=-no-pie` instead. If that doesn't work you might need to edit the Makefile by hand (don't know how though as I never tried this).

Comment: Is this a clean build?

Comment: Marco I tried using ccflags-y=-no-pie same error: http://codepad.org/SZSzcZY4

Comment: Hello @IanAbbott yes this is a fresh clean install. How did you know ? :-)

Comment: This is weird. I have your exact same system and GCC version (also with `--enable-default-pie`) and I am able to do `make menuconfig` and also compile the v5.16.10 kernel with no problem. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O3bo.png).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thank you for that screenshot I started thinking and realized make is complaining about the object files so deleted all the ones make complained about then ran make menuconfig and guess what ? Problem solved.

Comment: Ah, I guess that you had leftovers from previous builds then, which is probably what @IanAbbott was suggesting. In such cases `make clean` or `make distclean` should solve the problem. See also the descriptions under `make help`.

Comment: I took debian-11.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso and used that to create a clean fresh install but yes it had leftovers from previous builds and I did not understand what @IanAbbott was  trying to point out but I very much do now. Should I answer my own question so it helps someone else in the future or this is good enough ?